# jQuery wrap is forcing multiple document ready callbacks

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
function CreateRoundbox(selector, scope) {
    $(selector).wrap('<div class=\"' + scope + ' dialog\"><div class=\"bd\"><div class=\"c\"><div class=\"s\"></div></div></div></div>');
    $('div.' + scope).prepend('<div class=\"hd\"><div class=\"c\"></div></div>').append('<div class=\"ft\"><div class=\"c\"></div></div>');
}
```

Whenever I use this function and the "wrap" method is called it causes the $(document).ready() method to fire for a second time on the page.  Here is the call to the function (this lives in a document ready block):

```
CreateRoundbox(".roundbox", "roundbox-wrapper");
```

Has anyone ran into this before?  Am I using wrap wrong?

**UPDATE**

Fixed usage line, I accidentally added a dot in the scope literal

Comment: I'm confused, why are all " escaped ?

Comment: @ Zuul - lol... he just like it that way I guess... but it's not the issue.. is it?.. ;)

Comment: @Reigel, lol... nopes, but I just looking at that and couldn't grasp my head around it ;)

Comment: um...so this is old code that I'm supporting.  If you want to talk about the symantics of it I'm more than happy, however, it really has no bearing on the true issue....document.ready being called more than once on the page.

Comment: What is calling the code? Any chance it is being called by clicking on an `a` element?

Comment: @patrick The calling code is the second code block in the question.  It lives inside of a document.ready() block.  Any other document.ready() block on the page get's called twice....if I comment the "wrap" method in the first code block above it stops being called twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
function CreateRoundbox(selector, scope) {
                            //           v----> this will result to class=".roundbox-wrapper", which is, I guess, not the thing you want in there.. :)
    $(selector).wrap('<div class=\"' + scope + ' dialog\"><div class=\"bd\"><div class=\"c\"><div class=\"s\"></div></div></div></div>');
    $('div.' + scope).prepend('<div class=\"hd\"><div class=\"c\"></div></div>').append('<div class=\"ft\"><div class=\"c\"></div></div>');
   //     ^    ^
   //     |    |--- look at scope.... then, look here at the second argument, CreateRoundbox(".roundbox", ".roundbox-wrapper");
   //     |--- look at the dot.... :)   CreateRoundbox(".roundbox", ".roundbox-wrapper");

}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying...I'll update the example above...I just typed in the usage, and screwed it up ;)

Comment: lol with the down-vote... I hope at least the reason was explained... for further enhancement of the answer.. ;)

Comment: Yes, because it had no bearing on the actual answer (and I left a comment with an explanation, not to mention an update to the question).  Had this been the answer to the question it would have gotten an upvote. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks @reigel.  As stated before, this was a typo.  I appreciate you calling it out for me, but the typo wasn't intended.  Remember the reason for upvote/downvote on questions....so that others can get the best answer to the question....in that vein, it has no bearing on answering the question (once the typo was removed).  Nothing personal, SO rep is not everything my friend ;)